# How to create a nested structure when transforming dataframe to json object in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the function `toJSON` from the library `jsonlite` in R to transform a dataframe into json, however the formats that it returns by default are not suitable for me.

Considering the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), val1 = c("A", "B"), val2 = c("C", "D"))
```

If I use `toJSON(df)`, here's what I get:

```
[{"id":1,"val1":"A","val2":"C"},{"id":2,"val1":"B","val2":"D"}]
```

Instead what I want is as close as possible to this:

```
[
  "1": {"val1":"A","val2":"C"},
  "2":{"val1":"B","val2":"D"}
]
```

How can I transform `df` in a way that I can accomplish it? Just to be clear, my case has a very long dataframe with additional columns. I want the value of one specific column to be the key to the rest of the row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to `split` by 'id' and then apply `toJSON`

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(split(df[-1], df$id))
```

If we want to remove the `[]`

```
gsub("[][]", "", toJSON(split(df[-1], df$id)))
#{"1":{"val1":"A","val2":"C"},"2":{"val1":"B","val2":"D"}}
```

Comment: Nice! Can I get rid of the list thought? I got ```{"1":[{"val1":"A","val2":"C"}],"2":[{"val1":"B","val2":"D"}]} ```

Comment: @JoséLuizFerreira Try with `auto_unbox = TRUE`